# World's capital cities shapefile?

Tags: data

I'm looking for a shapefile containing the locations of all the world's capitals as of (around) 2016?

Answer (score 11):

Natural Earth provides a [populated places layer](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/) which has a capital attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Another obvious place to get names and location is the [geonames](http://www.geonames.org/) website. If you go to the [download](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/) page you can download data just as cities or the whole dataset which includes everything.